# The device cannot start . (code 10) error in umdf driver development

Tags: c++, c, wdk, umdf

I am trying to develope Umdf driver and i am completly naive to driver developement, I have taken a wdk sample code from following url :-

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Biometric-Driver-718005d7

I have changed the hardware id in the inx file and rebuilt the driver project and installed the resulting driver on a separate windows 7 pc. Driver got installed successfully but there is one error showing up :-

The device cannot start . (code 10)

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible thing i am missing ? I just want to test the drivers loading successfully.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the issue, but in the link you provided, under the OS requirements section it shows that the Client would require 'Windows 8'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually it is written there that it requires windows 8 but i think there must some way to make it run on windows 7. because iam using wdk 8.1 it works for windows 7. I dont know what exactly should be done to make it work.

Comment: This http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/code-10-error.htm link says: Cause of the Code 10 Error

A Code 10 error is generated when Device Manager can't start the hardware device, a situation usually caused by outdated or corrupted drivers.

A device may also receive a Code 10 error if a driver generates an error that Device Manager doesn't understand. In other words, a Code 10 error can sometimes be a very generic message indicating some kind of unspecified driver or hardware problem.

Comment: You can see my answer here where I explain step by step https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913695/403999 I am using windows 10 as a host and target machine. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

[In this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134010/An-UMDF-Driver-for-a-Virtual-Smart-Card-Reader) I found interesting remark:

> The .INF file used to install the virtual device is almost identical to the one from the UMDFSkeleton example. Just one row was added:
>
> UmdfKernelModeClientPolicy=AllowKernelModeClients
>
> To allow a kernel-mode driver to load above the user-mode driver and to deliver requests from the kernel-mode to the user-mode driver.
> I'm not exactly sure of which kernel mode driver runs above the virtual reader driver, but removing this line from the inf file, we simply do not get any I/O request notifications in our Queue object.

After adding this row in section [MyDevice_Install.NT.Wdf] and reinstalling driver my device startup normally.